# Spliting ArrayList into 2D ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < costs.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(twoDArrayList);
        for (int j = 0; j < cities.size(); j++){
            if (i==0 || i%cities.size() != 0){
                twoDArrayList.get(j).add(costs.get(i));
            } 
        }
    }
```

It is supposed to split an ArrayList (costs) and put values into a 2D ArrayList (twoDArrayList). This almost works except the code just puts the same values into each ArrayList within twoDArrayList. Here is the output:

```
begin execution
[Seattle, NewOrleans, LosAngeles, Tucson, Chicago, Miami, Omaha]
[[], [], [], [], [], [], []]
[[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]
[[0, 2706], [0, 2706], [0, 2706], [0, 2706], [0, 2706], [0, 2706], [0, 2706]]
[[0, 2706, 1136], [0, 2706, 1136], [0, 2706, 1136], [0, 2706, 1136], [0, 2706, 1136],        [0, 2706, 1136], [0, 2706, 1136]]
...etc.
```

I need it to move so that the arrayList is :

```
[0][2706][1136][etc...]
```

Thanks!

Here is the full code:

```
private static ArrayList<String> cities;
private static ArrayList<Integer> costs;
private static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> twoDArrayList;


public TSP(Scanner inFile) {
    cities = new ArrayList<String>();
    costs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String newCities;
    newCities = (inFile.nextLine());
    String[] stringArray = newCities.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++){
        cities.add(stringArray[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(cities);


    twoDArrayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();



    for (int i = 0; i < cities.size(); i++){
        twoDArrayList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>()); 
    }


    while (inFile.hasNextInt()){
        int newCost = inFile.nextInt();
        costs.add(newCost);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < costs.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(twoDArrayList);
        for (int j = 0; j < cities.size(); j++){
            if (i==0 || i%cities.size() != 0){
                twoDArrayList.get(j).add(costs.get(i));
            } 
        }
    }

    System.out.println(twoDArrayList.get(0).get(0));
    System.out.println(twoDArrayList.get(0).get(1));
    System.out.println(twoDArrayList.get(0).get(2));
    System.out.println(twoDArrayList.get(2).get(0));
    System.out.println(twoDArrayList.get(2).get(1));
    System.out.println(twoDArrayList.get(2).get(2));

}
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what's in the initial arraylist and what's supposed to be in the 2D arraylist, knowing the types (initialization of lists) would be nice too.

Comment: I edited the original question.

Comment: Please show the following: The original arraylist contents; The expected output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < costs.size(); ++i){
            System.out.println(twoDArrayList);
                if ((i+1)%cities.size() != 0 && j < cities.size()){
                    twoDArrayList.get(j).add(costs.get(i));
                }
                else {
                    ++j;
                }
            }
        }
```

or maybe this is what you want

```
    int j = 0;
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < costs.size(); ++i){
        if (count  % cities.size() != 0 && j < cities.size()){
            twoDArrayList.get(j).add(costs.get(i));
            ++count;
        }
        else {
            count = 2;
            ++j;
            if (j < cities.size()) twoDArrayList.get(j).add(costs.get(i));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(twoDArrayList);
```

Comment: This was smart, I didn't know you could put that check for size inside of the if statement! This almost works, I just have to figure out how to get the rest of the values. I will play around with it, thanks!

Comment: Things fall apart when I get to index 1. I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want 2 or more column in one value?

example

```
<cities>    <costs>    <distance>
Seattle     58         594
NewOrleans  74         434
LosAngeles  42         43
Tucson      43         456
Chicago     20         248
Miami       90         109
Omaha       45         85
```

All the above in the 2d Array? If so.

```
ArrayList twoDArrayList= new ArrayList<List>();
twoDArrayList.add(new ArrayList<String>());  //Cities
twoDArrayList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>()); //Costs
twoDArrayList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>()); //Distance
```

To add a value u need to do this

```
list.get(0).add("Enter a place"); //Adding a location
list.get(1).add(50);              //Adding a cost for the location you just added
list.get(2).add(534);             //Adding distance for the location you just added
```

To get values

```
list.get(0).get(i);   //gets location at index i
list.get(1).get(i);   //gets cost at index i
list.get(2).get(i);   //gets cost at index i
```

Need more information on what your input is.